# How to search using intitle:searchText using YouTube API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using YouTube API to search for videos and it's working just fine. I am wondering what changes I will have to make to search for intitle text.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the [YouTube API documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started), you cannot find any key word about this [`intitle:"search term"`]. So, it seems that this way of searching or filtering the results is not yet supported in the YouTube API.

As of now, the only way to filter the results of the API, is by using the [`q` parameter](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#q) of [`Search: list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list).

> The **q** parameter specifies the query term to search for.
>
> Your request can also use the Boolean NOT (-) and OR (|) operators to
>   exclude videos or to find videos that are associated with one of
>   several search terms. For example, to search for videos matching
>   either "boating" or "sailing", set the q parameter value to
>   boating|sailing. Similarly, to search for videos matching either
>   "boating" or "sailing" but not "fishing", set the q parameter value to
>   boating|sailing -fishing. Note that the pipe character must be
>   URL-escaped when it is sent in your API request. The URL-escaped value
>   for the pipe character is %7C.

If you want to support this intitle text in the API, then I recommend you to create a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/list?q=label:APi-YouTube) about this.

Hope this information helps you.